# Canvas circle are not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am creating a Map using d3js library and pointing some circle on particular locations and trying to create click event on these circle but these circles are not clickable.
Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>A D3 Map, points plotted with canvas instead of SVG</title>
<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}


#points{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}

.layer{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-10;
}

.tile {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 18px;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}   

.credit{
    position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
    padding: 9px 20px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.credit a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ddd;
}


</style>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.tile.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div id="map">
        <canvas>
            <div id="points" ></div>
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="credit"><p>Data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> Tiles &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a></p></div>
</div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

/* global variables and initial canvas space set up*/

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var prefix = prefixMatch(["webkit", "ms", "Moz", "O"]);
console.log(width,height)
var dataSet = "";

d3.csv("/../map2/karriereTutor.csv", function(error, dataset) {
  dataSet = dataset;
  createMap(dataset) 
});

var tile = d3.geo.tile()
    .size([width, height]);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
.scale((1 << 24) / 2 / Math.PI)
.translate([width / 2, height / 2]); // just temporary

$('.arc').on('click',function(){
  console.log('asdfd')
})

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.scale(4.5 << 12)
    .scaleExtent([1 << 9, 12 << 23])
    .translate([width / 3  ,3000])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var container = d3.select("#container")
        .style("width", width + "px")
        .style("height", height + "px")
        .call(zoom)
        .on("mousemove", mousemoved)

var base = d3.select('#map');

var chart = d3.select('canvas')
            .attr("class", "layer")
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

var context = chart.node().getContext('2d');

var locations = d3.select('#points');


var layer = d3.select('.layer');

var info = base.append("div")
    .attr("class", "info");

zoomed();

function createMap(dataset) {

  var dataBinding = locations.selectAll("points.arc")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("arc", true)
    .attr('id',function(d){ return d.city })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return projection([d.y,d.x])[0]})
    .attr("y", function(d) {return projection([d.y,d.x])[1]})
    .attr("radius", 5)
    .attr("fillStyle", "#ff0000")
    drawCanvas();
}

function drawCanvas() {

    var elements = locations.selectAll("div.arc");
    elements.each(function(d) {
        var node = d3.select(this);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(node.attr("x"), node.attr("y"), node.attr("radius"), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = node.attr("fillStyle");
        context.fill();        
        context.closePath();
    })
}


function reDraw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    drawCanvas();
}

function zoomed() {
  var tiles = tile
      .scale(zoom.scale())
      .translate(zoom.translate())
      ();

  projection
      .scale(zoom.scale() / 2 / Math.PI)
      .translate(zoom.translate());

    d3.selectAll("div.arc")
        .attr("x", function(d) {return projection([d.y,d.x])[0]})
        .attr("y", function(d) {return projection([d.y,d.x])[1]})
        reDraw();

  var image = layer
      .style(prefix + "transform", matrix3d(tiles.scale, tiles.translate))
      .selectAll(".tile")
      .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; })


  image.exit()
      .remove();

 image.enter().append("img")
 .attr("class", "tile")
      .attr("src", function(d) { return "http://" + ["a", "b", "c"][Math.random() * 3 | 0] + ".tile.openstreetmap.org/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .style("left", function(d) { return (d[0] << 8) + "px"; })
      .style("top", function(d) { return (d[1] << 8) + "px"; })
}



function mousemoved() {
  // for(var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++){
  //   var projectionPoints = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
  //   // console.log(dataSet[i].x, projectionPoints[1])
  //   if(Math.round(projectionPoints[1]) == Math.round(dataSet[i].x)){
  //     console.log(dataSet[i].city)
  //   }   
  // }
  info.text(formatLocation(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this)), zoom.scale()));
}

function matrix3d(scale, translate) {
  var k = scale / 256, r = scale % 1 ? Number : Math.round;
  return "matrix3d(" + [k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, r(translate[0] * scale), r(translate[1] * scale), 0, 1 ] + ")";
}

function prefixMatch(p) {
  var i = -1, n = p.length, s = document.body.style;
  while (++i < n) if (p[i] + "Transform" in s) return "-" + p[i].toLowerCase() + "-";
  return "";
}

function formatLocation(p, k) {
  var format = d3.format("." + Math.floor(Math.log(k) / 2 - 2) + "f");
  return (p[1] < 0 ? format(-p[1]) + " S" : format(p[1]) + " N") + " "
       + (p[0] < 0 ? format(-p[0]) + " W" : format(p[0]) + " E");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### I am using d3.js for creating map and here is csv file for create these circle's location

```
x,y,name,city
48.0851267,11.198654,karriere tutor,Wörthsee
52.2815691,7.443409099999999,karriere tutor,Rheine
48.2629984,11.4339022,karriere tutor,Dachau
49.7019294,9.2559214,karriere tutor,Miltenberg
47.697371,9.5629717,karriere tutor,Meckenbeuren
48.5667364,13.4319466,karriere tutor,Passau
52.4357364,8.6159777,karriere tutor,Rahden
49.6743636,12.1489337,karriere tutor,Weiden in der Oberpfalz
47.7782704,9.612130299999999,karriere tutor,Ravensburg
48.3705449,10.89779,karriere tutor,Augsburg Bayern
51.9032375,8.385753500000002,karriere tutor,Gütersloh
53.6764136,10.2378854,karriere tutor,Ahrensburg
51.3876468,10.7465696,karriere tutor,Straussberg
49.749992,6.6371433,karriere tutor,Trier
52.52000659999999,13.404954,karriere tutor,Berlin
54.3232927,10.1227651,karriere tutor,Kiel
51.4969802,11.9688029,karriere tutor,Halle (Saale)
51.6659316,8.7276375,karriere tutor,Borchen
52.3472237,14.5505672,karriere tutor,Frankfurt (Oder)
54.0729431,9.9840158,karriere tutor,Neumünster Holstein
53.9317752,9.5051475,karriere tutor,Itzehoe
53.5395845,8.580942499999999,karriere tutor,Bremerhaven
54.19517639999999,9.1019015,karriere tutor,Heide Holstein
51.8368113,10.7844266,karriere tutor,Wernigerode
52.9154545,12.7990783,karriere tutor,Neuruppin
52.21697469999999,13.453792,karriere tutor,Zossen
53.2464214,10.4115179,karriere tutor,Lüneburg
50.8021728,8.7667933,karriere tutor,Marburg
53.8654673,10.6865593,karriere tutor,Lübeck
51.8205718,9.8683087,karriere tutor,Einbeck
50.0522076,8.6952638,karriere tutor,Neu-Isenburg
51.2964148,6.8401844,karriere tutor,Ratingen
51.2041968,6.6879511,karriere tutor,Neuss
50.0294877,8.6949231,karriere tutor,Dreieich
51.3387609,6.5853417,karriere tutor,Krefeld
49.4874592,8.466039499999999,karriere tutor,Mannheim
54.0924406,12.0991466,karriere tutor,Rostock
54.08654629999999,13.3923414,karriere tutor,Greifswald
47.84199820000001,12.9728226,karriere tutor,Freilassing
50.4358385,7.825795299999999,karriere tutor,Montabaur
53.2778837,9.7240138,karriere tutor,Tostedt
49.8028671,8.603536199999999,karriere tutor,Pfungstadt
48.8914741,9.034192899999999,karriere tutor,Hardthof bei Markgröningen
48.6471033,9.4519635,karriere tutor,Kirchheim unter Teck
48.6893963,10.1610948,karriere tutor,Heidenheim an der Brenz
47.6779496,9.173238399999999,karriere tutor,Konstanz
50.5558095,9.6808449,karriere tutor,Fulda
53.6355022,11.4012499,karriere tutor,Schwerin Mecklenburg
51.3127114,9.4797461,karriere tutor,Kassel Hessen
50.0782184,8.239760799999999,karriere tutor,Wiesbaden
48.4010822,9.987607599999999,karriere tutor,Ulm Donau
48.5950369,8.8671577,karriere tutor,Herrenberg
50.1109221,8.6821267,karriere tutor,Frankfurt am Main
52.3758916,9.732010400000002,karriere tutor,Hannover
48.1351253,11.5819805,karriere tutor,München
51.3396955,12.3730747,karriere tutor,Leipzig
50.937531,6.9602786,karriere tutor,Köln
51.5135872,7.465298100000001,karriere tutor,Dortmund
51.4556432,7.0115552,karriere tutor,Essen Ruhr
53.07929619999999,8.8016936,karriere tutor,Bremen
53.5510846,9.9936819,karriere tutor,Hamburg
50.14720579999999,8.824969099999999,karriere tutor,Maintal
48.8940624,9.195464,karriere tutor,Ludwigsburg Württemberg
49.9456399,11.5713346,karriere tutor,Bayreuth
52.2688736,10.5267696,karriere tutor,Braunschweig
50.2612094,10.962695,karriere tutor,Coburg
50.3569429,7.5889959,karriere tutor,Koblenz am Rhein
47.9837999,10.1801883,karriere tutor,Memmingen
51.3670777,7.4632841,karriere tutor,Hagen Westfalen
51.1652199,7.0671161,karriere tutor,Solingen
53.1434501,8.214552099999999,karriere tutor,Oldenburg (Oldb)
51.1804572,6.4428041,karriere tutor,Mönchengladbach
51.4185682,6.884522599999999,karriere tutor,Mülheim an der Ruhr
49.0134297,12.1016236,karriere tutor,Regensburg
49.47741,8.445179999999999,karriere tutor,Ludwigshafen am Rhein
49.4771169,10.988667,karriere tutor,Fürth Bayern
51.0504088,13.7372621,karriere tutor,Dresden
50.8216502,6.1320672,karriere tutor,Würselen
51.2562128,7.150763599999999,karriere tutor,Wuppertal
50.73743,7.0982068,karriere tutor,Bonn
48.7781001,8.0875217,karriere tutor,Karlsruhe Baden
48.7758459,9.1829321,karriere tutor,Stuttgart
51.2277411,6.7734556,karriere tutor,Düsseldorf
48.1916623,11.6460441,karriere tutor,Unterföhring
50.22683079999999,8.6181618,karriere tutor,Bad Homburg vor der Höhe
50.09563620000001,8.776084299999999,karriere tutor,Offenbach am Main
50.17874,8.47191,karriere tutor,Königstein im Taunus
49.3063689,8.6427693,karriere tutor,Walldorf Baden
50.98476789999999,11.02988,karriere tutor,Erfurt
49.24015720000001,6.996932699999999,karriere tutor,Saarbrücken
52.3905689,13.0644729,karriere tutor,Potsdam
49.4521018,11.0766654,karriere tutor,Nürnberg Mittelfranken
51.9606649,7.6261347,karriere tutor,Münster Westfalen
49.9928617,8.2472526,karriere tutor,Mainz am Rhein
52.1205333,11.6276237,karriere tutor,Magdeburg
47.9990077,7.842104299999999,karriere tutor,Freiburg im Breisgau
50.1467469,8.561455500000001,karriere tutor,Eschborn Taunus
49.8728253,8.6511929,karriere tutor,Darmstadt
48.6813312,9.0088299,karriere tutor,Böblingen
52.0302285,8.532470800000002,karriere tutor,Bielefeld
52.844198,8.053015799999999,karriere tutor,Cloppenburg
53.7513549,9.6632521,karriere tutor,Elmshorn
48.5788725,7.8160821,karriere tutor,Kehl Rhein
```

Comment: The `div` elements are not part of the HTML DOM so they do not get mouse events. Like you update the map location handle the mouse down, traverse the div list and determine which dot is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've implemented an enter/update/exit cycle with canvas by using DOM nodes (unrendered in this case), but these DOM nodes don't interact at all with the canvas - canvas is a stateless collection of pixels. As a result, any mouse interaction with the canvas can only interact with the canvas as a whole - a pixel cannot have its own mouse click event.

Luckily there are a number of methods that can be used to track the mouse over the canvas and relate it to drawn shapes.

The easiest way straight out of the box is probably to use `d3.forceSimulation` without any actual simulation. It comes with a handy method that uses a quadtree to find a what node is closest to a mouse action (it also allows one to specify a search radius). This has the benefit of being quick to code and fast to execute without the hassle of trying to learn about quad trees. *If you had shapes other than circles it might not be ideal*.

*force.find(x,y,r)` is only in d3v4 onwards, but it seems you are using both d3v3 and d3v4, so d3.forceSimulation will work in this example without modification*

Here's an example that tracks what city is closest to the mouse when over the canvas:

First we set the nodes:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation().nodes(dataset);
```

Then we find mouse position and find the nearest node:

```
 var xy = d3.mouse(this);               // get xy position of mouse
 var longlat = projection.invert(xy);   // convert it to a lat long
 var nearest = simulation.find(longlat[1],longlat[0]); // see what point is closest.
```

*A few notes here:*

- *you have labelled your longitudes as `y` in your csv and your latitudes as `x`, this is opposite normal convention, but to avoid making changes elsewhere in the code I've kept it. This is why nearest.find() uses latitude,longitude (y,x) here.*
- *A force layout uses the `x` and `y` properties to track node position, which is why I haven't specified any accessor functions as you already have x,y properties in your dataset*
- *As I'm comparing latitudes and longitudes in the find function, I'm comparing what circle is closer to the mouse by angular distance, not projected distance - this can be avoided with a bit of work that I won't speak to here as it is a separate issue, in this case compounded by the use of several coordinate systems: zoom, canvas, geographic, and tile*

The above four or five lines of code, with a slight modification to your mouse over function to show the city closest to the mouse could look like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/6c08508da154df6f2cc69160bab6261e)

I haven't specified a search radius, but remember that it would be in degrees since the simulation is working with geographic coordinates (`d.x`,`d.y`).